# What is the difference between free and vmstat commands?

Tags: command-line, memory-usage

vmstat output:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 1  1      0 1001568  84736 500928    0    0    47    30   36   63  1  0 99  1
```

free output :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1918500     916592    1001908          0      84732     500576
-/+ buffers/cache:     331284    1587216
Swap:      1948668          0    1948668
```

How total memory in `vmstat` is calculated ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? The number that appears under the column `free` in the `vmstat` command is the same number under `free` in the `free` command. Same goes for `buffers` and `cached`.

Comment: aren't  the same concerning memory usage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manpages: [free](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free), [vmstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vmstat)

> **free** displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap
>   memory in the system, as well as the buffers used by the kernel. The
>   shared memory column should be ignored; it is obsolete.
>
> **vmstat** reports information about processes, memory, paging, block IO,
>   traps, and cpu activity.
>
> The first report produced gives averages since the last reboot.
>   Additional reports give information on a sampling period of length
>   delay. The process and memory reports are instantaneous in either
>   case.